# Can´t replicate "Run locally" for lambda visual studio code

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I have an existing project with lambdas in netcore2.1.

Recently I discovered the aws toolkit for VS Code and there is a great function that I want on my project

[image: Run Locally | Debug Locally]

When I created a test sam application and I navigate to the function Lambda Handler I notice VS Code adds the next options:

- Run Locally
- Debug locally
- Configure

If I click configure it shows a file in .aws/templates.json (but I also noticed that even if the file is missing it works on the test project)

I tried to replicate that file, and also the yaml file to describe my function, and the aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json

But nothing make appears the options, also I tried using the same functionhandler

[image: no functions available]

But nothing seems to make appear that run locally|Debug locally options

Does anyone knows how to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with the template.yaml and the handler.

```
  Handler: LoginSatFunction::LoginSatFunction.Function::FunctionHandler
```

It is essential to check the naming convention [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-programming-model-handler-types.html)

After having the correct naming in the handler, it worked like a charm.

Also, there is an issue in Visual Studio Code regarding Code Lens when using Environment Variables without apostrophes '', I reported it [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/issues/683).

So you should also check your Environment Variables in yaml to have apostrophes as a workaround meanwhile the bug is solved.